# What is wrong with my code? Looking for the length of the shortest string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing an assignment that asks for the length of the shortest string in an array. It should return 0 if the array is empty. I keep getting an error message that it doesn't handle ties.

Also, a test array `arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'aa']` returns a value of `3` instead of `2` as it should...

```
function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {
  var array;
  if (arr.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof array === "undefined") {
            array = arr[i].length;
        } else if (arr[i].length < array) {
            array = arr[i].length;
        } 
        return array;
      }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return` is in the wrong place

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: Please add what error you are getting.

Comment: @epascarello Sorryyy. Anyways I upvoted your comment so not all that evil.

Answer (score 1):

Someone pointed it out in the comments, just move your `return` out of the body of the `for` loop.

```
function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {
  var array;
  if (arr.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof array === "undefined") {
            array = arr[i].length;
        } else if (arr[i].length < array) {
            array = arr[i].length;
        } 
      }
     return array;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'aa'];

document.write(getLengthOfShortestElement(arr));
```